# Delay the start of message consumption

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, reactor-kafka

I have a very simple Reactor Kafka consumer.

However, in order for the message to be handled properly, couple of @Postconstruct should be executed beforehand.

The @Postconstruct will initialize some objects in memory, prepare data, etc...

If the messages start being consumed, but the @Postconstruct is not complete, the message handling will fail for sure.

The @Postconstruct needs some time to complete, roughly 3ish seconds.
What I tried:
Therefore, currently, in my code, I would just handle the messages, and for the first 3ish seconds, all messages processing will fail, and I would put the failed messages in another topic.

At some point, after the 3ish seconds, the @Postconstruct is complete, the messages are being processed normally, happy.

However, I found this very redundant, I have another topic and another job which existence is just here to re process the messages failed within those 3 seconds.

Is there a simpler way, to tell Reactor Kafka to only start consuming, only once the @Postconstruct is complete (maybe by sending some signal within the app), or maybe even just to wait 3ish seconds?

So far, I tried this:

```
  public Flux<String> myConsumer() {
        return KafkaReceiver
                .create(receiverOptions)
                .receive()
                .delayUntil(a -> Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(4)))
                .flatMap((oneMessage) ->
                        Mono.deferContextual(contextView -> {
                            var scope = ContextSnapshot.setAllThreadLocalsFrom(contextView);
                            try (scope) {
                                return consume(oneMessage);
                            }
                        }), 500)
                .name("greeting.call")      //1
                .tag("latency", "low")  //2
                .tap(Micrometer.observation(observationRegistry));
```

However, it is not doing what I expect, it is just delaying.

Comment: have you tried delaySubscription() ?

Comment: You can try to raise a custom event when `@PostConstruct` is done; annotate `myConsumer` with `@EventListener`. So the consumption will start only on PostConstruct end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not `subscribe()` to the flux in a post construct method. Instead, implement `SmartLifecycle` and subscribe in `start()`.

Or use an event listener and only subscribe after the context is refreshed.

That way, all beans will be fully wired up before you start to receive the records.